# How to do three-bend arrowed line in flowcharts drawn using Tikz?

Tags: latex, tikz

Something like this:
[image]

I googled but wasnt lucky enough to find one such example. I'd appreciate if someone could provide a Tikz example for 3-bend lines used in flowchart.

Comment: Please add a compilable [mre] that shows us how you constructed the diagram without the bend arrows. I'm sure we can then help you add the arrows.

Comment: Sorry but I dont have MRE for this - I'm trying to find the Latex example that can do the 3-bent arrow. The flowchart in the screenshot was created using Powerpoint, not Latex.

Comment: Here a starting point for you https://texample.net/tikz/examples/flexible-flow-chart/